# c# не получается добавить ссылку на службу (soap)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, wcf

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть проект ASP net, мне нужно использовать внешний soap Веб сервис в проекте.
Сам сервис крутиться на 1С,имеет авторизацию через логин и пароль, причем логин на кириллице, пароль - латиница. В Visual Studio выбираю подключить новую ссылку на службу WCF, ввожу URL адрес с wsdl, у меня появляется сообщение, в котором сказано, что нужно авторизоваться
[image: сообщение при нажатии на кнопку Go].
Далее нажимаю Да, получаю окно авторизации [image: требуется ввести логин и пароль]
Ввожу логин/пароль - и не пускает, снова открывается проверка учетных данных.
При этом если вводить в браузере/ postman - все работает прекрасно, открывается структура xml ответа.
Я пробовал переводить логин / пароль к ToBase64 таким образом `Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s2))` но разницы никакой.
Исходя из этого, как можно обойти этот момент, никогда не сталкивался с таким или можно написать самому клиент без ссылки на службу? ( если есть пример буду очень благодарен)

UPD. 23.02.2022
Версии IDE (обе обновлены по состоянию на текущую дату): Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 / 2022 - в обоих версиях проблемы.

Пробовал тоже самое сделать в обычном проекте WinForms (net.framework 4.8), результат тотже:
[image: net framework 4.8]
[image: тоже самое]

Comment: Возможно, проблема в использовании .net core. Попробуйте создать ASP NET (Framework) проект и там добавить аутентификацию. Если работает с Framework - проблема в поддержке WCF на Core

Comment: Также, стоит включить в вопрос версию VS

Comment: Пробовал, все равно проблема таже и с asp net (framework 4.8) и просто winworms